# Serving static contents through HTTPS on Amazon CloudFront

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am a bit confused on how to make CloudFront work as a CDN under SSL.

My whole website runs under HTTPS, by using a (not-self-signed) wildcard SSL Certificate:
let's say https://www.mysite.com

I created a new distribution in CloudFront, setting mysite.com as origin, and setting only HTTPS as behaviour, and match view protocol.

When in my html in insert

```
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"//XXXX.cloudfront.net/css/style.css\" />
```

this generates an HTTP request and that the browser blocks.

[image: General Options]

[image: Origins]

[image: Behaviours]

[image: Google Chrome network panel]

[image: Google Chrome console log error]

Comment: Just to confirm here..you set the behavior to "HTTPS-only" right? If that is the case, why are you using href="// ? Non secure connections will fail.

Comment: yes, i set "HTTPS-only" and i tried in html both //xxxx.cloudfront.net/... and  https:// xxxx.cloudfront.net/... the request is done from an ssl page https://mysite.com/mypage.html

Comment: Ok, are you able to add a screenshot (you can black out/blur any sensitive data) of the "General","Origins" and "Behaviors" tabs to your post so I can double check them?

Comment: yes, i improved the question with some snapshots

Comment: Thanks, that helps. It appears as though either the site has some redirects that may be interfering. If I curl the non-secure cloudfront URL manually I receive the error "Request could not be satisfied". If I curl the secure URL manually I receive a 301 permanent redirect replacing the cloudfront URL with your domain's URL.

Comment: there's a redirect to force http to https

Comment: Are you only forcing a protocol change or is the https://domain/$1 hardcoded?

Comment: surely the protocol in htaccess, there's also a redirect to m.domain.com for detected mobile devices

Comment: Ok, so CloudFront appears to be properly configured and working properly, however I believe something server-side is causing problems. If you would like we can take this into a chat and I can try to debug it further with you. I headed to lunch now, but will be back soon.

Comment: Add your answer so i can accept it, at least i know the issue is not amazon-side. In any case thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason.
the origin domains was mydomain.com while on the webserver there is a redirect from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com.

It was sufficient to create a new distribution with origin name: www.mydomain.com